# I am trying to make a functions that counts the occurrence of letter diagonally top left to bottom right of a matrix

Tags: python

This is the main question
Write a function named find_longest_string(legoString,n) that finds and returns the longest
diagonal string from the upper-right triangle of the matrix representation of the brick placement.
The longest diagonal string is defined as a string that contains the maximum occurrences of a
letter on the same diagonal. In case there are multiple solutions i.e. diagonal strings of the
same maximum lengths, you can return any of the valid solutions. Fig 5 shows a computation
of a valid solution. This function must have two parameters, legoString - a string returned from
the function named “place_random_bricks”, and n - the number of columns on the baseplate.

[In this example the letter G would be occurring the most](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWPXc.png)

```
def find_longest_string(legoString, n):

    list2 = []
    countr = ""
    countb = ""
    countg = ""
    county = ""
    countc = ""
    for i in range(len(legoString)):
        list = []
        if i % n == 0: #guarantees that row will only have required amount of columns(no more no less)
            sub = legoString[i: i + n] #i starts at 0 and so add number of columns for first row and continue
            #list = [] #create empty list each time a row is created

            for j in sub:

                list.append(j)
                list2.append(j)

            answer = ''.join(''.join(tup) for tup in list)
            answer2 = ''.join(''.join(tup) for tup in list)
            print(answer)  # prints list before it is reset

            for index in range(len(answer)):
                if answer2[index] == answer[index-1]:
                    if answer2[index] == "R":
                        countr = countr + "R"

                    elif answer2[index] == "B":
                        countb = countb + "B"

                    elif answer2[index] == "G":
                        countg = countg + "G"

                    elif answer2[index] == "Y":
                        county = county + "Y"

                    elif answer2[index] == "C":
                        countc = countc + "C"

    print(countr, countc, county, countb, countg)

    if len(countr) >= len(countb) and len(countg) and len(county) and len(countc):
        return countr

    elif len(countb) >= len(countr) and len(countg) and len(county) and len(countc):
        return countb

    elif len(countg) >= len(countr) and len(countb) and len(county) and len(countc):
        return countg

    elif len(countc) >= len(countr) and len(countg) and len(county) and len(countb):
        return countc

    elif len(county) >= len(countr) and len(countg) and len(countb) and len(countc):
        return county
```

Comment: What's the question?  Did  this program run fine or not working?  It's not clear here.

Comment: No it didn't run fine, I get more values than what would be there

Comment: `if len(countr) >= len(countb) and len(countg) and len(county) and len(countc):` doesn't do what you think it does. You can't compare against multiple values like that. In your case, it would be better to compare against the `max` of the values on the right.

Comment: Using max now makes that final statement work better, but there seems to be something wrong with the way it counts the letters diagonally